# Setting default magnet app in Firefox, but I can't navigate to where the qbitorrent binary file is

Tags: permissions, firefox, qbittorrent

I've seen a lot of answers about opening magnet links in Firefox. A lot of them tell you to go to `about:config` and change network protocol handler ........ to false etc. I've done that.

Now I get an option to choose which application to open the magnet link with.
Now here is where my problem lies. I have Firefox installed as a snap package and qbittorrent as a flatpak. When prompted, I try to choose from Firefox which app to use for magnet links. The thing is the executable for qbittorrent lies in my /var/lib/flatpak/apps folder. When I try this from the prompt window within Firefox it tells me I don't have permission to open /var
What should I do?

Comment: Open it from within qbittorrent, and file a bug report against the AppArmor profile for the FireFox snap.

Comment: You should remove FlatPak and Snap versions of mentioned software and install normal versions from APT.

Comment: @N0rbert   I like using flatpak and snap  because of the security of sandboxing and the convenience of installing and getting the latest updates

Comment: @user535733  how do i do that exactly.? some help please

Comment: You must find whoever packaged the Snap you are using, and report the bug to them. One disadvantage of Snaps is you're on your own doing that. We do not provide support for bugs within Snaps if did not provide the software. Since it's Firefox, you must report the bug to Mozilla.